# What's the point of buffering a peripheral

Tags: microcontroller, fifo

I have seen in most modern microcontrollers that the peripherals are queued using a hardware FIFO. What's the point of getting a hardware FIFO? Most old microcontrollers like PIC and AVR doesn't have a hardware FIFO. Are there strong points that the designers design an FIFO queue at every peripheral like SPI or DMA or USART?

Comment: To let the CPU to do some better stuff than to wait or interrupt on each byte sent/received. DMA can achieve the same, though. But it is considerably more complex to use.

Comment: On NXP K66 they use DMA with On Chip SPI that has a FIFO.. On connecting directly the SPI with the microcontroller, still don't get the point of having a hardware fifo on the SPI peripheral itself

Comment: Your CPU wants to deal with words, but SPI just bangs in bits. You need some hardware to accumulate a few bits to make dealing with the data somewhat efficient.

Comment: USART overflow is common enough problem that even with 16 byte buffers they still have an Overflow error flag.  It is up to you to avoid these errors and check if any errors occur.

Comment: Sometimes both FIFO and DMA are available to let you choose the preferred method. As for the specific chip, the FIFO is designed to allow an easy method of "allowing a single write to
the command word followed by multiple writes to the transmit word" - as they state in the reference manual. If you have some *long* bursts of data, you better use DMA.

Comment: I think if the CPU is getting slowed down due to some processing the FIFO can handle that by buffering the data into the hardware FIFO... Is that a logical reason ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller So what's the situation with old microcontrollers like AVR and PIC where they don't hardware FIFO ? Should one write a Software queue ?

Comment: well, you simply *can't* do everything at the same speed (or at all) if you don't have hardware support for it. Many! systems depend on daisy-chained SPI slaves, and it makes a lot of sense for these to have a FIFO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### FIFO

FIFOs were in regular use in the late 1980's in UARTs. (I was using them regularly starting in 1989, for example.) The 16550 (and eventually the 16554 [quad UART]) made 16-byte FIFOs readily available. Given the processing speeds, interrupt latencies, and the increasing serial rates of the day it was very convenient and helpful.

The obvious benefit is that the interrupt (or polling) rate can be less frequent. If the overhead of events is expensive, lowering the frequency helps a great deal.

But there also are problems with using a FIFO (larger than 1 byte anyway.) The receive trigger level (these devices usually allowed some choices) means that the software doesn't examine any of the incoming data until that threshold is reached and an interrupt is triggered. Or, if the sender pauses for a while, the trigger threshold might *never* be reached. (This was handled sometimes by allowing a specified/documented worst-case delay -- often 4 character times -- and an interrupt would be triggered anyway if a delay like that occurred.) This can be bad for real-time systems or when processing packets and when the last fragment of a full packet is sitting in the FIFO with a long delay before the next packet is sent along. So there are trade-offs between better overall throughput and latency.

If the interrupt overhead isn't bad or if your data rates are slow enough it is probably simpler to do without the FIFO. Supporting a FIFO requires more code than not supporting one because the number of states and problems to worry about is increased.

### DMA

This can be very helpful, at times. For example, in the SiLabs (was Cygnal) C8051F06x (which I made a lot of use of, since it is the ***only*** MCU sporting a decent 16-bit ADC, let alone one that runs at \$1\:\text{MHz}\$ conversion rates), you don't have *any* option in the matter if you want to support the maximum ADC conversion rate of \$1\:\text{MHz}\$. The C8051F06x uses an 8051 core with only one DPTR. And it is way, way too slow to keep up. Without the DMA, the ADC converter's capabilities would have been inaccessible and therefore wasted.

DMA is usually added because there is at least *one* peripheral in the family that either requires it or else would struggle hard without one. Once added, it can be relatively easy to enable the DMA unit itself to support more devices. If that is easy to do and not too difficult to document and support, it's likely to be enabled. (You may also see DMA supporting memory to memory transfers.)

Some DMA isn't just "programming a few registers and letting it fly." It can actually be a more sophisticated state machine all of its own that allows you to program it for different tasks. Again, I'll happily bring up the C8051F05x MCU. It's DMA requires some "programming" to operate. And the documentation (when I was messing with it) was completely inadequate. (Unusable, in fact, as it wasn't possible to correctly program it for the ADC without additional information that was missing.) I had to ask SiLabs, who took a few weeks to track down, locate, and then ask the original DMA designer (who had done the work 8 years before) -- then in Singapore, I think -- in order to get my questions answered.

### Summary

Many ideas arrive when facing the problems caused when high data rates have to be supported. Hardware support, whether that is a FIFO or DMA or some other scheme, can be very helpful. Such solutions usually also come with their added problems (all swords are two-edged.) So there is a software and ongoing support price to pay in most cases. (And as in my case, delays due to having to track down a designer just to find out how to use it imply yet another kind of risk -- fewer people exist who know how something works and can help you *and* those attending delays in securing such help.) But usually it is worth paying, when a situation arises where you want a FIFO or DMA.

Answer (score 2):

Major purpose of hardware FIFO is to de-couple an input data rate (data frequently come on a fixed equidistant sample rate) from output rate, which can be prone to CPU delays due to various concurrent processes / interrupts. FIFO decoupling provides smooth data streams without under-runs or over-runs (assuming sufficient overall throughput of the processor in place). Software queue might serve the same purpose, but it carries software/code/timing overhead, and prone to the same possible lags. Hardware FIFO off-loads this burden to hardware using few watermark flags.